# Java nested for loops repeating incorrectly

Tags: java, arraylist, nested-loops

I created this package, and the problem is when is runs it repeats the same catalog entries between bins. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Issue probably in detailedInventory method. 
**It should** create a new random bin item (type, title, artist) for Bin B, not use the same element from Bin A, as it is doing now. Other than this, the output is correct. SKU numbers are correctly generated and displayed.

**What it should do:** The detailedInventory method should use a for-each loop to cycle through all the bins in the warehouse. For each bin, s should be extended by the String "Bin " followed by the name of the bin, followed by a colon and \n to start new line. Then it should cycle through all the bin items in the current bin, for each one extending s by a new line of text that begins with the result of looking up the current bin item’s SKU in the input catalog, and continue with a comma followed by the String representation of the bin item.

**Other information:**
* The values of i, when they correspond to the catalog, are objects. they are actually different types of physical media, such as DVDs or cassettes, with title,  artist and SKU attributes.

- Although it does not seem to make sense, the data should be generated randomly. (This class is part of a larger concept/lesson to illustrate inheritance.)
- I call the collection of all items in a bin that share the same SKU a “bin item”.
- Each object of the Bin class (shown in full code) represents a bin in a pretend warehouse. A Bin object has two instance variables: a String that contains the bin name and an ArrayList that contains a BinItem for each of the SKUs stored in the bin. The toString method of the Bin class uses the toString method of the BinItem class. It generates lists that only involve SKUs and quantities.

**Here is the output I see:**

```
Bin A:
DVD - Greatest Hits Volume 2 (Limp Bizkit), SKU 1234-0: 500
Cassette - The Best Of (Michael Jackson), SKU 1234-1: 25
DVD - Love Songs (Michael Jackson), SKU 1234-2: 7720

Bin B:
DVD - Greatest Hits Volume 2 (Limp Bizkit), SKU 1234-3: 1000
```

The bin item under Bin B should not be the same as A.

**The output should look something like this:**

```
Bin A:
CD - The Later Years (Shania Twain), SKU 1234-0: 500
Cassette - Greatest Hits Volume 2 (The Beatles), SKU 1234-1: 25
Cassette - Greatest Hits Volume 1 (Shania Twain), SKU 1234-2: 7720

Bin B:
Cassette - Greatest Hits Volume 2 (Michael Jackson), SKU 1234-3: 1000
```

***Update:***
I tried to create another method to retrieve an item based on the SKU, but now compiler complains of an Incompatible Types error on the Bolded line in the modified detailedInventory loop to use it?:

```
public static MusicMedia getMediaBySKU(ArrayList<MusicMedia> catalog, String sku)
   {
    for ( MusicMedia m : catalog ) {
        if ( m.getSKU().equals(sku) )
            return m;
    }
    return null;
}
```

modification:

```
for ( Bin bn : warehouse ){
    s += "Bin " + bn.getName() + ":\n";

    for ( BinItem item : bn.getContents() ){
        MusicMedia mm = getMediaBySKU(catalog, item.getSKU());

        s += mm + ", " + item + "\n";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class testMusicMedia
{
    public static ArrayList<MusicMedia> MakeMusicCatalog( int size )
    {
       String[] titles =
         {
           "Greatest Hits Volume 1", "Greatest Hits Volume 2",
           "The Best Of", "Love Songs",
           "The Early Years", "The Later Years"
         };
       String[] artists = 
         {
           "Michael Jackson", "Eminem",
           "The Beatles", "Shania Twain",
           "Limp Bizkit"
         };
       ArrayList<MusicMedia> catalog = new ArrayList<MusicMedia>();
       Random rn = new Random();
       for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
       {
            MusicMedia m;
            int mediatype = rn.nextInt( 3 );
            String title = titles[ rn.nextInt( titles.length ) ];
            String artist = artists[ rn.nextInt( artists.length ) ];
            String sku = "1234-" + i;
            if ( mediatype == 0 )
                m = new CompactDisk( title, artist, sku );
            else if ( mediatype == 1 )
                m = new DigitalVideoDisk( title, artist, sku );
            else
                m = new CassetteTape( title, artist, sku );
            catalog.add( m );
       }
      return catalog;
    }   

    public static String lookupMedia( ArrayList<MusicMedia> catalog,
        String sku )
    {
        for ( MusicMedia m : catalog )
        {
            if ( m.getSKU().equals( sku ))                  
            return "SKU is in catalog";
        }
        return "SKU not in catalog";
    }

    public static String detailedInventory( ArrayList<MusicMedia> catalog, ArrayList<Bin> warehouse )
    {
        String s = "";
        for ( Bin bn : warehouse ){
            s += "Bin " + bn.getName() + ":\n"; 
              for (int i = 0; i < bn.getContents().size(); i++){
                s += catalog.get(i) + ", " + bn.getContents().get(i) + "\n";
              }
        }
        s += "\n";
        return s;
    }  

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ArrayList<MusicMedia> catalog = MakeMusicCatalog( 10 );
        ArrayList<Bin> warehouse = new ArrayList<Bin>();
        Bin a = new Bin( "A" );
        Bin b = new Bin( "B" );
        warehouse.add( a );
        warehouse.add( b );
        a.add( new BinItem( "1234-0", 500 ) );
        a.add( new BinItem( "1234-1", 25 ) );
        a.add( new BinItem( "1234-2", 7720 ) );
        b.add( new BinItem( "1234-3", 1000 ) );
        System.out.println( detailedInventory( catalog, warehouse ) ); 
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
public class MusicMedia
{
    private String myTitle,
    myArtist,
    mySKU;

    public MusicMedia( String title, String artist, String sku )
    {
        myTitle = title;
        myArtist = artist;
        mySKU = sku;
   }
   public String getTitle()
   {
       return myTitle;
    }
    public String getArtist()
    {
        return myArtist;
    }
    public String getMediaType()
    {
        return "Unknown";
    }
    public String getSKU()
    {
        return mySKU;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return " - " + getTitle() + " (" + getArtist() + ")";
    }
}


  public class Disk extends MusicMedia
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Disk
     */
    public Disk( String title, String artist, String sku )
    {
        super(title, artist, sku);
    }

    public String getMediaType()
    {
        return "Disk"; 
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getMediaType() + super.toString();
    }
}
```

I also have an identical CassetteTape class that also extends MusicMedia. Also two other subclasses of Disk, called CompactDisk and DigitalVideoDisk. These two are also almost identical to each other, so I have pasted the DVD class below.

```
public class DigitalVideoDisk extends Disk
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class DigitalVideoDisk
     */
    public DigitalVideoDisk( String title, String artist, String sku )
    {
        super(title, artist, sku);
    }

    public String getMediaType()
    {
        return "DVD";
    }
}
public class BinItem
{
    private String mySKU;
    private int    myQuantity;
    public BinItem( String sku, int quantity )
    {
        mySKU = sku;
        myQuantity = quantity; 
    }
    public String getSKU()
    { 
        return mySKU;
    }
    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return myQuantity;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "SKU " + getSKU() + ": " + getQuantity();
    }
 }

public class Bin
{
    private String  myName; //bin name
    private ArrayList<BinItem>   myContents; //contains a binItem
    public Bin( String name )
    {
      myName = name;
      myContents = new ArrayList<BinItem>();
    }   
    public String getName()
    {
      return myName;
    }    
    public ArrayList<BinItem> getContents()
    {
        return myContents;
    }   
    public void add( BinItem b )
    {        
        myContents.add( b );
    }    
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "Bin " + myName + ":\n";
        for ( BinItem b : myContents )
            s += b + "\n";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What a long question. Is it possible to trim it down that what is necessary to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @LutzHorn I can try...wanted to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Repeated output from nested for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277928/java-repeated-output-from-nested-for-loop)

Comment: @Mauren updated this question to include the new compiler error